# Unity 5 Error: Failed to re-package resources

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

When I try to build any android project in Unity, I get these errors:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\Users\alexi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/alexi/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[

]
stdout[

]
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String[] progress_strings, Single progress_value, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.CompileResources (System.String stagingArea, System.String packageName, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidLibraries androidLibraries)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcessInternal (System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

And this error:

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\Users\alexi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/alexi/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[

]
stdout[

]
```

I have these packages installed in Android SDK:
[link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn6Fz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed it. For some reason having Android SDK Build-Tools 24 installed caused the issue. I uninstalled that using the Android ADK Manager (leaving Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.3 installed), and it fixed the issue.

Comment: I ran into the same problem earlier this week.